# How To Know Country name from device ip address?

Tags: android

I can get the country name from a device using the location of the device's sim, but for a tablet without a sim this won't work.  How can I get the country code or country name from the device's ip when it's connected to internet?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how exact you want to be - noting that this technique is not very accurate anyway! There are all sorts of ways of defeating geolocation by IP address.

However, there are websites that you can query with the IP address and it will return a country.

But if you don't want to go online to find out, you will need to take a dump of the current list, encode it in a lookup table, and store it inside your program.

You will not want to store every address - there are 4 billion possible ones - but instead store large ranges. This will reduce the table size considerably.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a GeoIP library for Android you can use in your project.
It uses an online API to get the country from the IP address.

https://github.com/seventhmoon/GeoIp-android

Here's a snippet on how to use it:

```
   ApiManager apiManager = new ApiManager(Volley.newRequestQueue(context));
   apiManager.getGeoIpInfo(new Response.Listener<GeoIpResponseModel>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(GeoIpResponseModel response) {
            //This is how you get the information.
            //not all attribute are listed
            String country = response.getCountry();
            String city = response.getCity();
            String countryCode = resopnse.getCountryCode();
            double latitude = response.getLatitude();
            double longtidue = response.getLongitude();
            String region = response.getRegion();
            String timezone = response.getTimezone();
            String isp = response.getIsp();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            String errorMessage = error.toString();
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks marmor, i have tested this code using emulator but the result is null.

Comment: I checked with real device still it is not working!! null value shown.

Comment: limit 1000 request per day, see more here https://ipapi.co/#pricing